# How do you use the new ^ system?

Tags: minecraft-commands

How is this system different than the old one? Also, what new capabilities does it bring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduced in 1.13, the caret notation `^` denotes the direction relative to the player's head rotation. Like the tilde notation `~`, it can be used in any command that supports relative coordinates.

The general syntax is `^<left> ^<up> ^<forward>`. Use negative values to specify the opposite direction. Using `/tp` as an example, to teleport a player 5 blocks to his/her right hand side, execute the command `/tp ^-5 ^ ^`.

Refer to [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands).